# Is there a reason the partition tool GParted doesn't show a percentage finish number initially?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, progress

I am using GParted more, and it seems to do a reliable work.

I just wonder why if the tasks is to resize a 250GB partition to 190GB, and then create a new partition, the first 10, 15 minutes, there is only a blue bar moving left and right, but there won't be an indicator showing how many percent is done.  Then after that 10 to 15 minutes, it does show 1:05:00 left to finish the job.

**Update:** at first I thought there is no percentage or time remaining at all... but after waiting for 10, 15 mintues, it does show.  I just wonder why it didn't show at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is already a drop-down box which gives you status updates on the current operation, but if you don't know the terminology in the partition modification process, it's of no use to you! Your idea has been [suggested](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=432141) a few times before, and will likely be added in the future (hint: nag them for a feature request =] )

If you want a temporary solution, the resize2fs tool has a progress bar and does resizing of ext2 and ext3 file systems.